# Is it possible to write custom primitives for GNU Emacs with C?

Tags: c, emacs, elisp, primitive

GNU Emacs is easily extended with Emacs Lisp. In some cases you may hit a performance wall even after byte compiling. In this situation it would be useful to be able to write C functions that you could call from Emacs Lisp code. Is this possible? How do you do it? Is there example code?

Comment: Don't forget, that it is almost always *possible* to do it in C.  You seem to be asking: "Is it feasible to do so?", or "Has someone already done this, and if so, where is it so that I can check?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is [this (Writing Emacs Primitives)](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Writing-Emacs-Primitives.html) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4):

There is no interface to do this, and unless you were aiming to do something like image/video processing in emacs, I see no way it could be useful. C does not automatically make things faster *unless you can bypass expensive data structures and work on the data in its representation*. If your C code had to work with elisp data structures, it would not be significantly faster than elisp, and it would probably be slower than elisp if anybody ever bothered to make the elisp environment highly-optimizing...

Comment: I think both answers are right in a way. I was surprised the emacs documentation actually provides a way to do what you wanted, but it is *modifying emacs*, not loading an extension into an existing emacs. If you really need to do this tho, it may be what you want.